# Child div doesn't fill div

Tags: html, css

I'm facing an issue while building a custom table. I already tried fiddling around with the Chrome Inspection Tool and changing everything, but nothing get me towards the goal. I already searched all around SO, but nothing could help me. I can't be the only one that is facing this issue, seriously...

The table is already implemented into the page, but I made a simplified version to reproduce the issue.

```css
.scrollwrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.outtertable {
  transition: .2s;
  color: #333;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  display: flex;
}

.theader {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.tbody:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.item {
  min-width: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollwrapper">
  <div class="outtertable theader">
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
  </div>

  <div class="outtertable tbody">
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The result of the code above is this:
[image: Screenshot_78.png]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** An answer was given, but I need to say that the items should get nearer each other when the div is shrinking in width.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. You didn't ask a question. "Child div doesn't fill div" doesn't tell me if you perceive that the innermost set of children is the problem, or the middle set of children is the problem. Is the problem occurring always, or only when you make the window small? (Some of these questions I'm asking seem obvious... but you're just requiring us to guess and assume...)

Comment: @JosephHansen I want that the darker content fills the outter div, but it sadly doesn't.

Comment: When I click "Run code snippet" inside Stack Overflow, it works. (I'm on updated Chrome and macOS.)

Comment: Why not just add `background-color` to `.scrollwrapper`?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 60.0.3112.113 and it doesn't work here: http://prntscr.com/gfdqzw

Comment: @ovokuro Because when I hover, it'll seem broken. And also, on mine, I attached a "onclick" on it, which doesn't fire outside that area, and that's an issue.

Comment: @Fusseldieb ok, I posted an answer before seeing your comment about attaching an event. Let me know if it won't work...

Comment: TIL that you can turn your tabs into pyramids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you can't do both a flexbox and a table with the same HTML elements. But, you can solve your specific problem, if you just focus on what you have: groups of side-by-side divs that need to shrink or expand, and might overflow.

You can see the confusion in your code. You want the 3rd-level children to overflow and scroll relative to the 1st-level parent, but you're trying to color the 2nd-level children, not the 3rd-level.

In this case, you're not dealing with rows and columns. The length of your rows will only be the length of the available space in the container (1st-level parent); the "rows" (2nd-level) will not stretch to contain all of the content (3rd-level) because they are `display: flex;`.

[image]

As you can see, the row scrolls with the children inside the top parent element, rather then the children scrolling inside the row.

To put background color on all of the elements in a row, you actually have to put it on the individual elements. But, you can say that only children of a particular class will have the background color, like this:

```
.tbody:hover > .item {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
```

The following code does what you want:

```css
.outtertable {
  transition: .2s;
  color: #333;
  display: flex;
}

.outtertable>.item {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
}

.theader {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.tbody:hover>.item {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.item {
  min-width: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="outtertable theader">
  <div class='item'>Item</div>
  <div class='item'>Item</div>
  <div class='item'>Item</div>
  <div class='item'>Item</div>
  <div class='item'>Item</div>
  <div class='item'>Item</div>
  <div class='item'>Item</div>
  <div class='item'>Item</div>
  <div class='item'>Item</div>
  <div class='item'>Item</div>
  <div class='item'>Item</div>
</div>

<div class="outtertable tbody">
  <div class='item'>Item</div>
  <div class='item'>Item</div>
  <div class='item'>Item</div>
  <div class='item'>Item</div>
  <div class='item'>Item</div>
  <div class='item'>Item</div>
  <div class='item'>Item</div>
  <div class='item'>Item</div>
  <div class='item'>Item</div>
  <div class='item'>Item</div>
  <div class='item'>Item</div>
</div>
```

Notice: you can get rid of the `.scrollwrapper` div and it works the same.

Comment: Worked perfectly.Thank you so much for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `background-color` to the wrapper, and move the hover effect to the row:

```
.tbody:hover .item {
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```css
.scrollwrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
}

.outtertable {
  transition: .2s;
  color: #333;
  display: flex;
}

.theader {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.tbody:hover .item {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.item {
  min-width: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollwrapper">
  <div class="outtertable theader">
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
  </div>

  <div class="outtertable tbody">
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.scrollwrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.outtertable {
  transition: .2s;
  color: #333;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  display: flex;
}

.theader {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.tbody:hover .item {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.item {
  min-width: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollwrapper">
  <div class="outtertable theader">
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
  </div>

  <div class="outtertable tbody">
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It still doesn't contract =/ (Look at mine, mine when the div/window goes smaller, the items get nearer at each other)

Comment: This does **not** answer the question in a _useful_ way. **why** do you believe this is the answer? **how** does it work? Simply telling someone to _change their code_ or just _giving someone working code_ without any context or meaning does not help them learn what they did wrong, and is also not as useful for future readers.

Comment: I tried all scenarios and this worked . So I posted . It depends on asker to accept it or not as answer.